# */link in robots.txt - Does this block all or just url ending with /link?

Tags: robots.txt

I have a Rails-application with products where the products can be found at:

mydomain.com/thisproduct

if the user clicks on the link that leads to the manufacturers website, this is done by using a function "link" with the following url:

mydomain.com/thisproduct/link

Google seems to index this quite peculiarly by indexing that page as my page but with the content of the manufacturers website. So, I want to block this from being indexed in robots.txt.

```
This is my robots.txt:

# See http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/norobots.html for documentation on how to use the robots.txt file
#
# To ban all spiders from the entire site uncomment the next two lines:
# User-Agent: *
# Disallow: /
Disallow: /sokresultat/*
Disallow: */link
```

Where the last line is what my question relates to:

Do this block all urls that ends with link? And, more importantly, **does it block anything else**? I am afraid this will de-index my entire site, through that wildcard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like, after some additional, research that wildcards are supported differently between search engines. This works for Google and could be verified in Google Webmaster Tools.